# CasperJS - how to treat an 'click' inside an loop?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, click, casperjs

I have problems to treat things after 'click' inside a loop that is inside a evaluate function. I don't know another way to treat that.

'Le' Code...

```
links = this.evaluate(function(){
      story_boxes = __utils__.getElementsByXPath('//div[@id="contentCol"]//div[@id="stream_pagelet"]/div[contains(@id,"topnews_main_stream")]/div/div//div[contains(@data-ft,"{")]');

      for(x=0;x<=story_boxes.length;x++){
        story_box = story_boxes[x];
        boxID = story_box.getAttribute('id');

        //Is this feed a sponsored?
        sponsored = story_box.querySelector('a.uiStreamSponsoredLink');
        if(sponsored){
          console.log("SPONSORED? " + sponsored   );
          try{
            elink = story_box.querySelector('div > div > div > div > div > div > a');
          }
          catch(e){
            console.log("Ooops! An error occured, sorry! " + e);
          }

          if(elink){
            console.log("FOUND IT!");
            crap = setTimeout( function(){
              elink.click(); //where can I treat this?
            }, 1000);

            break;
          }
          else {
            console.log("NO DONUT FOR YOU!");
          }
          console.log("\n\n#########");
        }
      }
      console.log("#####");

    });
    //... more irrelevant things
```

The question is how can I treat each click ? I need just the subtree of the result of the click. I don't know if I'm clear here. Probably not... :P

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're asking how to handle the result of the click.

If the click leads to a new page load, then you can simply add a waiting step after your code and let CasperJS handle the loading of the page:

```
casper.then(function(){
    var success = this.evaluate(function(){
        ...
        if(elink){
            console.log("FOUND IT!");
            crap = setTimeout( function(){
                elink.click(); //where can I treat this?
            }, 1000);

            return true;
        }
        ...
        return false;
    });

    if (success) {
        this.wait(1100, function(){
            // TODO: do something with the loaded page
        })
    } else {
        // TODO: do something on fail
    }
})
```

If the click changes the existing page, then you need to wait for such a change. There are a lot of functions that CasperJS provides for such a case. All of them begin with `wait`. For example:

```
casper.then(function(){
    this.evaluate(...);
}).wait(1100).waitForSelector('some new element selector', function _then(){
    // TODO: do something with the loaded page
}, function _onTimeout(){
    // TODO: do something on fail
})
```